# Event disappears on button Style designer

Tags: delphi, events, firemonkey, expander, firemonkey-style

I would like to create a personalized style on expander in firemonkey.
But when I want to add an event on a button (I replace the checkbox by a button that I have drag and drop from palette), then when I save, the event disappear and is not triggered.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : [image]

When I create/select an event from the dropdownmenu, when I saved the style, the selected event diseaper from the `onclick` event but my code is always written

EDIT 2 :

I have an `Expander`, and I would like to replace the default `Checkbox` by a `Button`.

So, I `Edit` the `Default Style` and replace the default `Checkbox` by a `SpeedButton` (like in the picture above)

At this `Button`, I want to add an `Event` on the `OnClick`. So I double click on the empty space beside the `OnClick` event and write the code into this event created automatically.

Once my code written, I'm go back in the `Style Designer` and I see the `Event` attached to the `OnClick` button, then I save the style.

But when I return to the `Style Designer`, the `Event` is not attached anymore to the `Onclick` event but he's still write/exist in code.

I tell myself I made a wrong saved, but the button him is still here, so I for me It's really saved.

I hope I'm clear.
[image]

LAST EDIT :

```
    object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  StyleBook = StyleBook1
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Expander1: TExpander
    Align = Client
    ShowCheck = False
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    StyleLookup = 'Expander1Style1'
    Text = 'Expander1'
    TabOrder = 0
    ContentSize = '455'
  end
  object StyleBook1: TStyleBook
    Styles = <
      item
      end
      item
        Platform = 'Windows 10 Desktop'
        ResourcesBin = {
          464D585F5354594C4520322E3501060F457870616E646572315374796C653103
          D9030623457870616E646572315374796C6531457870616E646572427574746F
          6E5374796C6531037E0F061D457870616E646572315374796C6531436865636B
          426F785374796C653103D00B005450463007544C61796F757400095374796C65
          4E616D65060F457870616E646572315374796C653105416C69676E070643656E
          7465720A53697A652E57696474680500000000000000A008400B53697A652E48
          65696768740500000000000000F007401453697A652E506C6174666F726D4465
          6661756C7408085461624F726465720251000A5452656374616E676C65000541
          6C69676E0708436F6E74656E74730A46696C6C2E436F6C6F7207097846464630
          463046300748697454657374080A53697A652E57696474680500000000000000
          A008400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000F007401453697A652E
          506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080C5374726F6B652E436F6C6F72070978
          46464343434343430007544C61796F757400095374796C654E616D6506066865
          6164657205416C69676E0703546F700A53697A652E5769647468050000000000
          0000A008400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000C803401453697A
          652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080005545465787400095374796C65
          4E616D6506047465787405416C69676E0706436C69656E74064C6F636B656409
          0748697454657374080C4D617267696E732E4C65667405000000000000008000
          400D4D617267696E732E526967687405000000000000008000400A53697A652E
          576964746805000000000000809208400B53697A652E48656967687405000000
          00000000C803401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C7408045465
          7874060454657874155465787453657474696E67732E576F7264577261700800
          000F54457870616E646572427574746F6E00095374796C654E616D6506066275
          74746F6E05416C69676E07084D6F73744C656674064C6F636B6564090A53697A
          652E57696474680500000000000000C803400B53697A652E4865696768740500
          000000000000C803401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080B
          5374796C654C6F6F6B75700623457870616E646572315374796C653145787061
          6E646572427574746F6E5374796C653100000C545370656564427574746F6E0C
          62746E416464416374696F6E095374796C654E616D6506115370656564427574
          746F6E315374796C6505416C69676E07094D6F737452696768740A506F736974
          696F6E2E5805000000000000C09908400A53697A652E57696474680500000000
          000000C803400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000C80340145369
          7A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080B5374796C654C6F6F6B757006
          0D6164646974656D627574746F6E0454657874060C62746E416464416374696F
          6E00000000005450463007544C61796F757400095374796C654E616D65062345
          7870616E646572315374796C6531457870616E646572427574746F6E5374796C
          65310A53697A652E57696474680500000000000000A008400B53697A652E4865
          696768740500000000000000F007401453697A652E506C6174666F726D446566
          61756C74080756697369626C6508085461624F72646572025200125442757474
          6F6E5374796C654F626A65637400095374796C654E616D65060A6261636B6772
          6F756E6405416C69676E070643656E746572074F706163697479050000000000
          00000000000C536F757263654C6F6F6B7570061B57696E646F77732031302044
          65736B746F707374796C652E706E670A53697A652E5769647468050000000000
          0000D002400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000D002401453697A
          652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C740808577261704D6F6465070643656E
          74657207486F744C696E6B0E010F536F75726365526563742E4C656674050000
          0000000000FA05400E536F75726365526563742E546F7005000000000000009E
          074010536F75726365526563742E526967687405000000000000008A06401153
          6F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000080A407400001055363
          616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500
          000000000000BC06400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000
          ED074010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000D0064011
          536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000000F7074000010553
          63616C6505000000000000008000400F536F75726365526563742E4C65667405
          00000000000000FA06400E536F75726365526563742E546F7005000000000000
          009E084010536F75726365526563742E526967687405000000000000008A0740
          11536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000080A4084000000B
          466F63757365644C696E6B0E010F536F75726365526563742E4C656674050000
          0000000000DC05400E536F75726365526563742E546F7005000000000000009E
          074010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000F605401153
          6F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000080A407400001055363
          616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500
          000000000000A506400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000
          ED074010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000B9064011
          536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000000F7074000010553
          63616C6505000000000000008000400F536F75726365526563742E4C65667405
          00000000000000DC06400E536F75726365526563742E546F7005000000000000
          009E084010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000F60640
          11536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000080A4084000000A
          4E6F726D616C4C696E6B0E010F536F75726365526563742E4C65667405000000
          00000000DC05400E536F75726365526563742E546F7005000000000000009E07
          4010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000F6054011536F
          75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000080A40740000105536361
          6C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563742E4C656674050000
          0000000000A506400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000ED
          074010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000B906401153
          6F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000000F707400001055363
          616C6505000000000000008000400F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500
          000000000000DC06400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000
          9E084010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000F6064011
          536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000080A4084000000B50
          7265737365644C696E6B0E010F536F75726365526563742E4C65667405000000
          00000000FA05400E536F75726365526563742E546F7005000000000000009E07
          4010536F75726365526563742E526967687405000000000000008A064011536F
          75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000080A40740000105536361
          6C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563742E4C656674050000
          0000000000BC06400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000ED
          074010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000000000D006401153
          6F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000000F707400001055363
          616C6505000000000000008000400F536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500
          000000000000FA06400E536F75726365526563742E546F700500000000000000
          9E084010536F75726365526563742E526967687405000000000000008A074011
          536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000080A4084000001354
          6F756368416E696D6174696F6E2E4C696E6B0E00000F54466C6F6174416E696D
          6174696F6E00084475726174696F6E05000000000017B7D1F13F0C50726F7065
          7274794E616D6506074F7061636974790A537461727456616C75650500000000
          0000000000000953746F7056616C7565050000000000000080FF3F0754726967
          67657206104973457870616E6465643D66616C73650E54726967676572496E76
          65727365060F4973457870616E6465643D747275650000001254427574746F6E
          5374796C654F626A65637400095374796C654E616D65060A6261636B67726F75
          6E6405416C69676E070643656E7465720C536F757263654C6F6F6B7570061B57
          696E646F7773203130204465736B746F707374796C652E706E670A53697A652E
          57696474680500000000000000D002400B53697A652E48656967687405000000
          00000000D002401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C7408085772
          61704D6F6465070643656E74657207486F744C696E6B0E010F536F7572636552
          6563742E4C6566740500000000000000FA05400E536F75726365526563742E54
          6F70050000000000000095074010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500
          0000000000008A064011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000
          0000809B07400001055363616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365
          526563742E4C6566740500000000000000BC06400E536F75726365526563742E
          546F700500000000000080DF074010536F75726365526563742E526967687405
          00000000000000D0064011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000
          00000080E907400001055363616C6505000000000000008000400F536F757263
          65526563742E4C6566740500000000000000FA06400E536F7572636552656374
          2E546F70050000000000000095084010536F75726365526563742E5269676874
          05000000000000008A074011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D050000
          00000000809B084000000B466F63757365644C696E6B0E010F536F7572636552
          6563742E4C6566740500000000000000DC05400E536F75726365526563742E54
          6F70050000000000000095074010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500
          000000000000F6054011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000
          0000809B07400001055363616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365
          526563742E4C6566740500000000000000A506400E536F75726365526563742E
          546F700500000000000080DF074010536F75726365526563742E526967687405
          00000000000000B9064011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000
          00000080E907400001055363616C6505000000000000008000400F536F757263
          65526563742E4C6566740500000000000000DC06400E536F7572636552656374
          2E546F70050000000000000095084010536F75726365526563742E5269676874
          0500000000000000F6064011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D050000
          00000000809B084000000A4E6F726D616C4C696E6B0E010F536F757263655265
          63742E4C6566740500000000000000DC05400E536F75726365526563742E546F
          70050000000000000095074010536F75726365526563742E5269676874050000
          0000000000F6054011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D050000000000
          00809B07400001055363616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F7572636552
          6563742E4C6566740500000000000000A506400E536F75726365526563742E54
          6F700500000000000080DF074010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500
          000000000000B9064011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000
          000080E907400001055363616C6505000000000000008000400F536F75726365
          526563742E4C6566740500000000000000DC06400E536F75726365526563742E
          546F70050000000000000095084010536F75726365526563742E526967687405
          00000000000000F6064011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000
          000000809B084000000B507265737365644C696E6B0E010F536F757263655265
          63742E4C6566740500000000000000FA05400E536F75726365526563742E546F
          70050000000000000095074010536F75726365526563742E5269676874050000
          00000000008A064011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D050000000000
          00809B07400001055363616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F7572636552
          6563742E4C6566740500000000000000BC06400E536F75726365526563742E54
          6F700500000000000080DF074010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500
          000000000000D0064011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000
          000080E907400001055363616C6505000000000000008000400F536F75726365
          526563742E4C6566740500000000000000FA06400E536F75726365526563742E
          546F70050000000000000095084010536F75726365526563742E526967687405
          000000000000008A074011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000
          000000809B0840000013546F756368416E696D6174696F6E2E4C696E6B0E0000
          0F54466C6F6174416E696D6174696F6E00084475726174696F6E050000000000
          17B7D1F13F0C50726F70657274794E616D6506074F7061636974790A53746172
          7456616C756505000000000000000000000953746F7056616C75650500000000
          00000080FF3F0754726967676572060F4973457870616E6465643D747275650E
          54726967676572496E766572736506104973457870616E6465643D66616C7365
          000000005450463007544C61796F757400095374796C654E616D65061D457870
          616E646572315374796C6531436865636B426F785374796C65310A53697A652E
          57696474680500000000000000A008400B53697A652E48656967687405000000
          00000000F007401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C7408075669
          7369626C6508085461624F7264657202120007544C61796F75740005416C6967
          6E07044C6566740A53697A652E576964746805000000000000009003400B5369
          7A652E4865696768740500000000000000F007401453697A652E506C6174666F
          726D44656661756C7408001154436865636B5374796C654F626A656374000953
          74796C654E616D65060A6261636B67726F756E6405416C69676E070643656E74
          6572074361704D6F6465070454696C65064C6F636B6564090C536F757263654C
          6F6F6B7570061B57696E646F7773203130204465736B746F707374796C652E70
          6E670A53697A652E57696474680500000000000000D002400B53697A652E4865
          696768740500000000000000D002401453697A652E506C6174666F726D446566
          61756C740808577261704D6F6465070643656E7465720D416374697665547269
          676765720707436865636B65640A4163746976654C696E6B0E010F536F757263
          65526563742E4C6566740500000000000000F803400E536F7572636552656374
          2E546F70050000000000000092064010536F75726365526563742E5269676874
          0500000000000000B0044011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D050000
          00000000009F06400001055363616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F7572
          6365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000B804400E536F75726365526563
          742E546F700500000000000000DB064010536F75726365526563742E52696768
          74050000000000000082054011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500
          000000000000EE06400001055363616C6505000000000000008000400F536F75
          726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000F804400E536F757263655265
          63742E546F70050000000000000092074010536F75726365526563742E526967
          68740500000000000000B0054011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D05
          000000000000009F074000000A536F757263654C696E6B0E010F536F75726365
          526563742E4C6566740500000000000000C000400E536F75726365526563742E
          546F70050000000000000092064010536F75726365526563742E526967687405
          0000000000000080034011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000
          000000009F06400001055363616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F757263
          65526563742E4C65667405000000000000008001400E536F7572636552656374
          2E546F700500000000000000DB064010536F75726365526563742E5269676874
          0500000000000000B8034011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D050000
          0000000000EE06400001055363616C6505000000000000008000400F536F7572
          6365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000C001400E536F75726365526563
          742E546F70050000000000000092074010536F75726365526563742E52696768
          74050000000000000080044011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500
          0000000000009F0740000007486F744C696E6B0E010F536F7572636552656374
          2E4C65667405000000000000008803400E536F75726365526563742E546F7005
          0000000000000092064010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500000000
          000000F0034011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000000000
          9F06400001055363616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F75726365526563
          742E4C6566740500000000000000C803400E536F75726365526563742E546F70
          0500000000000000DB064010536F75726365526563742E526967687405000000
          00000000B0044011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000000000
          00EE06400001055363616C6505000000000000008000400F536F757263655265
          63742E4C65667405000000000000008804400E536F75726365526563742E546F
          70050000000000000092074010536F75726365526563742E5269676874050000
          0000000000F0044011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D050000000000
          00009F074000000D416374697665486F744C696E6B0E010F536F757263655265
          63742E4C6566740500000000000000B404400E536F75726365526563742E546F
          70050000000000000092064010536F75726365526563742E5269676874050000
          0000000000E8044011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D050000000000
          00009F06400001055363616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F7572636552
          6563742E4C65667405000000000000008605400E536F75726365526563742E54
          6F700500000000000000DB064010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500
          000000000000AC054011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000
          000000EE06400001055363616C6505000000000000008000400F536F75726365
          526563742E4C6566740500000000000000B405400E536F75726365526563742E
          546F70050000000000000092074010536F75726365526563742E526967687405
          00000000000000E8054011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000
          000000009F074000000B466F63757365644C696E6B0E010F536F757263655265
          63742E4C65667405000000000000008803400E536F75726365526563742E546F
          70050000000000000092064010536F75726365526563742E5269676874050000
          0000000000F0034011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D050000000000
          00009F06400001055363616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F536F7572636552
          6563742E4C6566740500000000000000C803400E536F75726365526563742E54
          6F700500000000000000DB064010536F75726365526563742E52696768740500
          000000000000B0044011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D0500000000
          000000EE06400001055363616C6505000000000000008000400F536F75726365
          526563742E4C65667405000000000000008804400E536F75726365526563742E
          546F70050000000000000092074010536F75726365526563742E526967687405
          00000000000000F0044011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D05000000
          000000009F0740000011416374697665466F63757365644C696E6B0E010F536F
          75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000B404400E536F7572636552
          6563742E546F70050000000000000092064010536F75726365526563742E5269
          6768740500000000000000E8044011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F6D
          05000000000000009F06400001055363616C650500000000000000C0FF3F0F53
          6F75726365526563742E4C65667405000000000000008605400E536F75726365
          526563742E546F700500000000000000DB064010536F75726365526563742E52
          696768740500000000000000AC054011536F75726365526563742E426F74746F
          6D0500000000000000EE06400001055363616C6505000000000000008000400F
          536F75726365526563742E4C6566740500000000000000B405400E536F757263
          65526563742E546F70050000000000000092074010536F75726365526563742E
          52696768740500000000000000E8054011536F75726365526563742E426F7474
          6F6D05000000000000009F074000000000001654427574746F6E5374796C6554
          6578744F626A65637400095374796C654E616D6506047465787405416C69676E
          0706436C69656E74064C6F636B6564090C4D617267696E732E4C656674050000
          0000000000C000400A53697A652E576964746805000000000000C09A08400B53
          697A652E4865696768740500000000000000F007401453697A652E506C617466
          6F726D44656661756C74080D536861646F7756697369626C650808486F74436F
          6C6F720708636C61426C61636B0C466F6375736564436F6C6F720708636C6142
          6C61636B0B4E6F726D616C436F6C6F720708636C61426C61636B0C5072657373
          6564436F6C6F720708636C61426C61636B000000}
      end>
  end
end
```

Comment: I have edit my question.
So, I can't had an event to my "custom" button ?

Comment: Thank's for you're feedback

Comment: There's some problems with the `.fmx` you show, it doesn't match the image you show. The `btnAddActionClick` is missing from the `.fmx`. In order for us to have exactly the same code to work with, please create a new project, with nothing more than the `TExpander` on a form. Modify it as you want it to be (verify that the steps you explained earlier are valid), and then save the project and post the `.fmx` file you now have, instead of earlier posted `.fmx` file.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I think that the `btnAddActionClick` is missing from the .fmx because the .fmx has the content of the _form_, not the style.  He's trying to add the event to a component of the _style_, not the form.

I don't think it's possible to do that, even though the object inspector in the style designer appears to allow it.  But I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Yes, @Philip You are most probably right, I just wanted Guillaume to verify with the actual structure as it can't be seen.

Comment: Hello @TomBrunberg I have edit my first question ("LAST EDIT") with a new `.fmx` (on a new project) I have reproduce the same steps, but unfortunately, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an event in Style Designer. You should call `FindStyleResource` in the `OnApplyStyleLookup` event passing the `StyleName` of the object and return it as a `TFMXObject`, like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Expander1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var
  Control: Sender as TFmxObject;
  O: TFMXObject;
  Button: TSpeedButton;
begin
  O := Control.FindStyleResource('btnAddAction');
  if (Assigned(O) and (O is TSpeedButton)) then
    Button := O as TSpeedButton;
    if (Assigned(Button)) then
      Button.OnClick = btnAddActionClick;
end;
```